# WPF is maintain by Microsoft or WPF Community?

Tags: c#, wpf

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Gvr0d1vTQ4&list=PLdo4fOcmZ0oX-DBuRG4u58ZTAJgBAeQ-t&index=6

Navigate to 29.30. here one discussion is WPF is maintained by WPF Community, not my microsoft.

Please some one guide its true? Is WPF with (.net 5) maintained my community. I had search on google but found no luck.

Please reply.

Comment: Microsoft maintain wpf but they take pull requests. https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2020/09/30/wpf-survey.aspx?m=1

Answer (score 0):

Simply speaking, most of the .NET Core/.NET 5 components are [.NET Foundation projects](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf#net-foundation). Microsoft provides its engineering resources to lead the development of such projects, and the community (.NET developers from other companies, or individuals) contributes via pull requests. WPF and its core framework follow this convention.

[The slide](https://github.com/dotnet/maui#xamarinforms-vs-net-maui) you were referring to, however, talked about a separate topic. That is the WPF backend of MAUI, which maps the special XAML to WPF based controls (if you understand how Xamarin.Forms works today).

The WPF backend of Xamarin.Forms is in preview and [provided by the community](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/other/wpf). Microsoft sponsored some outsiders to develop that up, and it was not considered a core component of either WPF or Xamarin.Forms, because WPF is really an old technology with significant limitations.

As the next generation of Xamarin.Forms, MAUI will continue on this approach that Microsoft provides the official Windows backend based on WinUI3, while the outsiders can upgrade/maintain the WPF backend.

> Anyway the "WPF Community" term can be confusing.

More importantly, such an arrangement determines the technical support model,

- For backends fall under Microsoft's wings, Microsoft engineering/support team will work on issues reported by customers.
- For backend fall under community's umbrella, Microsoft's support contracts are not applicable. You have to rely on the community members to fix bugs or implement new features, or simply do it on your own.